# How to use vhd-util to manage snapshots

Tags: xen, vhd

I'm running several VMs within Xen, and now I'm trying to create/revert snapshots of my VMs.

Along with Xen and `blktap2`, another utility, `vhd-util` is also delivered, and according to its description, I guess I can use it to create/revert VM snapshots.

To create a snapshot is actually easy, I just call:

```
vhd-util snapshot -n aSnapShot.vhd -p theVMtoBackup.vhd
```

But when it comes to reverting a snapshot, things get really annoying.

The "revert" command requires a mandatory argument "`journal`", like this:

```
vhd-util revert -n aSnapShot.vhd -j someThingCalledJournalOfWhichIHaveNoIdea
```

And `vhd-util` expects some info from the journal, which means it's not some empty file you can write logs in.

But I've went through the code and the internet, still get no idea where this Journal comes from.

Similar question is asked 
http://xen.1045712.n5.nabble.com/snapshots-with-vhd-util-blktap2-td4639476.html but poor guy never get answered.

Hope someone here could help me out.

Comment: The answers belows perfectly explains how vhd snapshots work in detail, and for those who might be still looking for a solution to this problem, well,  here's what I do: there's **NO NEED** to call "vhd-util revert" at all! just pass the snapshot to tapdisk who will then create a virtual block device, all we have to do is to pass the virtual block device to qemu instead of the snapshot image itself, that's it. if any trouble using tapdisk, try google "tap-ctl".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use revert, all you need to do is shut down the VM, rename aSnapShot.vhd to theVMtoBackup.vhd and restart the VM.

Comment: Thanks Thanos! I finally get this to work! Turns out this is kinda some bug of libxl, it does not pass the tapdisk block to qemu but pass the raw VHD image instead.

Answer (score 2):

Creating snapshots in VHD works by putting an overlay over the existing VHD image, so that any change get written into the overlay file instead of overwriting existing data. For reading the top-most data is returned: either the data from the overlay if that sector/cluster was already over-written, or from the original VHD file if it was not-yet over-written.

The vhd-util command creates such an overlay-VHD-file, which uses the existing VHD image as its so-called "backing-file". It is important to remember, that the backing-file must never be changed while snapshots still using this backing-file exist. Otherwise the data would change in all those snapshots as well (unless the data was overwritten there already.)

The process of using backing files can be repeated multiple times, which leads to a chain of VHD files. Only the top-most file should ever be written to, all other files should be handled as immutable.

Reverting back to a snapshot is as easy as deleting the current top-most overlay file and creating a new empty overlay file again, which again expose the data from the backing file containing the snapshot. This is done by using the same command again as above mentioned. This preserves your current snapshot and allows you to repeat that process multiple times.
(renaming the file would be more like "revert back to **and** delete last snapshot".)

**Warning:** before re-creating the snapshot file, make sure that no other snapshots exists, which uses this (intermediate) VHD file as its backing file. Otherwise you would not only loose this snapshot, but all other snapshots depending on this one.

Comment: wow, thanks for such thorough explanation, saves me a lot of time digging the docs, really appreciate it!